# How to disable onResume() call if onActivityResult() is called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have refresh function called inside `onResume()` if user minimize app and then will come back it will refresh list of data from server. Problem is that same functionality but with different parameters (and different usecase) is used when user come back from another activity. It will refresh list only partially (not all data). Is there a possibility to block `onResume()` method call if `onActivityResult()` is called?

Comment: _onResume()_ is lifecycle of activity. It will be called everytime when user back to previous activity or after minimizing the app and back again

Comment: you should not try to block it, as you have to call `super.onResume` in your activity, as it is required for activity lifecycle. Instead use some condition in your overriden onResume to refresh or not refresh something

Comment: Problem is that if I came back from activity with specific resultCode, it will call refresh API call with parameter sent from that activity. Inside onResume is generic refresh of data. And if those two function are called, it will call API twice and I have duplicate data in my list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one way to achieve that,

```
onActivityResult
```

will get called before calling

```
onResume
```

So, you can add a flag there and check the necessary condition. Whether it came other screen or not.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 3214) {
cameFromOtherScreen = true; }

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
if(!cameFromOtherScreen) {
   //do your thing }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first set a global boolean variable like this:-

```
boolean isPaused = false;
```

now set a methods in your activity :-

```
@Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        isPaused = true;
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }
```

or in your onResume method:-

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if(isPaused){
         isPaused = false;
        super.onResume();
          }

    }
```